# Mark migrations as migrated after database import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku

I recently migrated my production server to Heroku. While doing so, I followed Heroku's [documentation to export and import my database to their servers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export).

Now when I try to migrate my database using `heroku run rake db:migrate` I get errors that tables already exist. It appears as though `migrate` is starting over from the beginning as if the database was new.

How can I fast forward `db:migrate` so it will start from the second most recent migration file?
I've made one change to my local database since the database import on production and now I need to migrate the production database.

Comment: Did you not dump `schema_migrations` when you backed up your old database? Rails keeps track of which migrations have been run inside the database so there shouldn't be any migration issues when copying databases.

Comment: I did "pg_dump -U postgres -Fc --no-acl --no-owner database_name > backup.dump". Shouldn't that have got it?

Comment: That should have gotten everything. Did you set up your database before restoring into it? That would have applied `schema.rb` to your database (which would have created all the tables). Some quick hack options (you'll have to manually ensure that everything is there and in the proper state if you do these): (1) delete all your migrations since they're supposed to be temporary and cleaned out now and then anyway, (2) manually populate `schema_migrations` so that `db:migrate` will think they've all been run.

Comment: What do you mean by "set up your database before restoring it"? Since I will never start with a new blank database I suppose I could just delete the old migrations. FYI, I can restore the database again, not much has changed since the previous restore.

Comment: Did you `rake db:setup` or anything? Or did you create the database and then restore into an empty database?

Comment: I don't remember but maybe not rake db:setup

Comment: You could try doing a `db:schema:dump` and comparing the new `db/schema.rb` with the old one. If there aren't any differences then you can probably delete your migrations and move on to more productive activities.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll just delete the migrations manually and move on to "more productive activities" :). If you would like credit, please add that as an answer.

Comment: I didn't really solve the problem, just sort of swept it under the rug so I don't think I deserve anything more than "thanks", cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I never plan to create a new empty database, I ended up simply moving all the old migrations from db/migrate to a folder I named db/archive.